# Script to automatically click a button repetitively in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a button that needs to be pressed repetitively every 5 seconds automatically.

The button is defined as :

```
<button id="refresh" class="btn- fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" value="referesh" (click)="ngOnInit()">&nbsp; Refresh</button>
```

After looking for solutions I wrote this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
  $('#refresh').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Though the above script worked in a HTML env., it didn't work in the angular scenario.

I am completely new to Angular and can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you create the component where the button is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing the button the angular way

like this

```
<button #myButton id="refresh" class="btn- fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" value="referesh" (click)="triggerClick()">&nbsp; Refresh</button>
```

and in your typescript, give myButton a ViewChild reference

```
@ViewChild('myButton') myButton : ElementRef;

triggerClick() {
    let el: HTMLElement = this.myButton.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    setTimeout(()=> el.click(), 5000);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in the ts file will this code go? Because I don't see triggerClick getting invoked anywhere. I added the code snippet you gave, but it didn;t work...

Comment: add that code in your component.ts and just call this.triggerClick() whenever you want to initiate click.

Comment: this.triggerClick() goes in the .ts file? And where exactly in the .ts file?

Comment: As my application is started, I want the button to be repetitively pressed automatically every 5 seconds. Where should I put the this.triggerClick() statement in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If you created the component where the button is, and if all you want to do is call the code that you defined in `ngOnInit` every 5 seconds, you could simply call the method directly

```
constructor()
{
    setInterval(() => this.ngOnInit(), 5000);
}
```

To make things cleaner, move the code that is in `ngOnInit` to a separate function (by definition, on INit should be called only once)

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.myMethod();//Initialisation
   setInterval(() => this.myMethod(), 5000);
}

meMethod()
{
   //Code you want to call repetitively
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function in component.ts then on click event you need to call that function.

> (click)="refresh()"

**component.html**

```
<button id="refresh" class="btn- fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" value="referesh" (click)="refresh()">&nbsp; Refresh</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
refresh() {
  console.log('Refresh Clicked')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to click on text automatically so give id to that text

```
<h6 class="pt-2" id="refresh">auto click me</h6>
```

Ts file

```
(document.getElementById('refresh').click())
```